# Find a function matching this scheme

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

As I'm building a model, I need a function equals to $+\infty$ in 0, $-\infty$ in R and 0 in $\frac{R}{2}$.

So it will looks like this (sorry for this bad drawing I'm at work). It definitely looks like a sigmoid, but I don't manage to find one that matches this.

[image]

Comment: $-\tan (\theta+R)$, this is approx

Comment: This doesn't go to $+ \infty$ when $\theta = 0$, but I agree that I want something looking that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x \longmapsto -\tan \left[\frac{\pi}{2}   \left(\frac{2 x}{R}-1\right)\right]$